# Protecting against problematic scraper \ mild DDoS from AWS servers

Tags: amazon-web-services, ddos

we currently have an issue where someone(s) with many different IP addresses, all belonging to AWS is scraping \ making many requests per second to our public server. User agents are randomized and there is no pattern to be found with which to block connections. We attempted blocking entire AWS ip ranges (which worked) but that ends up breaking some services we use (S3 uploads etc.) The only constant is that the referrer is always set to 'google.com', which obviously we don't want to block because there would be no way to access our site from a google search.

Any ideas?

Comment: Report it at https://aws.amazon.com/forms/report-abuse.

Comment: You say the addresses belong to AWS, but what do the reverse lookup hostnames look like? It may be outright abuse, or it could also be an "interesting" misconfiguration. Some redacted examples, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would be to grep through your logs for 'google.com'
 referrers, then script a whois lookup on the IPs to check for IPs which are coming from AWS IP space, then reject them on inbound port 80/443 TCP on your firewall.

To give you an idea:

```
whois <ip> | grep Amazon
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  <command to add IP to firewall reject/drop policy>
fi
```

That's what I would do if I decided I just wanted to block them. If this is giving you performance problems, it might be prudent to fix the performance issues rather than *just* block the cause of them. You may want to look into using nginx as a caching reverse proxy or something, if applicable to the type of site you're running.